# jQuery about changing the column and row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have write a click event, and to create a table using:

```
var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('foo');
                $.each($(this).get(0).attributes,function(i,attrib){
                    //var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('bar').text(attrib.name + ":" + attrib.value);
                    table.append('<tr><td>'+attrib.name+'</td><td>'+attrib.value+'</td></tr>');
                   // table.append(row);

                });
                $('#here_table').append(table);
```

The result is like:

name1 : value1

name2 : value2

But I want to change into:

name1   name2

value1  value2

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two separate arrays for `names` and `values` that you later use to build a single string for each of them:

```
var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('foo');
var names = [];
var values = [];
$.each($(this).get(0).attributes, function(i, attrib) {
    names.push(attrib.name);
    values.push(attrib.value);
});
var rowNames = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('bar').text(names.join(" "));
table.append(rowNames);
var rowValues = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('bar').text(values.join(" "));
table.append(rowValues);
$('#table').append(table);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in your way, how to make enough space for aligning name to value?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to collect names and values first and then put them into the two rows of your table. Sadly you cannot easily populate a table column by column

Something in the lines of

```
var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('foo');
var names = [];
var values = [];
$.each($(this).get(0).attributes, function(i, attrib) {
   names.push(attrib.name);
   values.push(attrib.value);
}

// now populate two lines
var row1 = $('<tr/>');
$.each(names, function(i, name) {
   var td = $('<td/>');
   td.text(name);
   row1.append(td);
}
table.append(row1);

var row2 = $('<tr/>');
$.each(values, function(i, value) {
   var td = $('<td/>');
   td.text(value);
   row2.append(td);
}
table.append(row2);
```